# Value-of in <a> html markup

Tags: html, xml, xslt, value-of

I have this XSL file :

```
<xsl:template match="attribute">
 <a  href="-">
    mylink
 </a>
 <xsl:value-of select="url" />
```

I want to put the value of my the url attribute in the href.

Do you know how to do this ?
Because `<a  href="<xsl:value-of select="url" />">` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
<a href="{url}">mylink</a>
```

Or

```
<a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
     <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   mylink
</a>
```

The former is an attribute value template. Read about them in more detail [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

Caveat: This works only if your input XML looks similar to the following (i.e. if `url` is really an element and `attribute` its parent element).

```
<attribute>
  <url>www.google.com</url>
</attribute>
```

You might have to adapt the above for your XML input (since you do not show it).